# Generic Constraints Syntax and Usage

Tags: c#, generics

Suppose I want to author a generic `Max` method which returns the maximum of two values. I can utilize the generic interface `IComparable<T>`: [`null` checks ignored]

```
static T Max<T>(T x, T z) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    return x.CompareTo(z) > 0 ? x : z;
}
```

fine. Now the first thing I don't get is the following extension to the above example:

```
static void Initialize<T>(T[] array) where T : new()
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        array[i] = new(T);
}
```

where would it be neccessary to adopt this syntax (`new()` in this context is confusing me here)? Moreover, I have seen the following generic template that befuddles me even further

```
class GenericClass<T> where T : SomeClass, Interface
                                      where U : new()
{ /* Some Code */ }
```

Here I assume that `T` is a type constraint that is *filtered* from the type constraint `U`. So if this is the case then we could write

```
class Magic<T>
{
    Magic<U> SomeOtherClass<U>() where U : T { /* Some Code */ }
}
```

do I have this right and how many levels of this sort of hierarchy is possible in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you've given an example of where the `new()` constraint is useful: if you want to populate an array with "new" objects, each of which is created by calling the parameterless constructor.

As for this:

```
class GenericClass<T> where T : SomeClass, Interface
                                  where U : new()
```

... that won't compile, as it's trying to constrain `U`, but that's not declared as a type parameter.

But your `Magic<T>` will compile, and will force `U` to be appropriately compatible with `T`. (The *exact* details are tricky; see the specification.)

For example, you could call

```
new Magic<Stream>.SomeOtherClass<FileStream>()
```

or

```
new Magic<IFormattable>.SomeOtherClass<int>()
```

Comment: The Specification you referred me to comes tomorrow :].  This may seem like a stupid question here, but I suppose you could have `Class SuperMagic<T> { SuperMagic<U> Magic<U>() where U : T { ... }` I take it this can go on forever? Also are `T` and `U` the only letters Permitted to signify generics? Thanks again for your time Jon. All the best.

Comment: @Killercam: It's not really clear what you mean by your example, to be honest. You should probably just try it. And no, the identifiers `U` and `T` here are arbitrary. They're just names. You can use them for types if you really want, and you can use any other name for a type parameter. The convention is something starting with `T` though.

Comment: @Killercam, here is the link to get the C# language specification - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593(v=vs.100).aspx, in particular section 4.4.4 covers constraints.